# Delphi local net app

Tags: delphi, sockets, drawing, client-server, delphi-7

Trying to learn how to make server-client apps and stuff like. I trying to draw circles(on mouse click) in all clients so this is how i trying to do that. But it's not working - no errors but form is empty. What i need to fix?
Client code

```
unit Client;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, {Figure, Ball,} IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, ScktComp;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    ClientSocket: TClientSocket;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);



  private

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  f:boolean;
  p:MyPoint;
  s:MyPoint;
  z:TCanvas;
  obj: MyFigure;
  pX, pY:Integer;
  myBuf: array[1..32] of Integer;
  dataBuf: array[1..32] of Integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  Timer1.Interval:=5;
  z:=Form1.Canvas;//TCanvas.Create;

  Button1.Caption:='Пуск';


  f:=false;

  ClientSocket.Port:=1234;
  ClientSocket.Active:= False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not f then
 begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
  Button1.Caption:='Стоп';
  f:=not f;
 end
else
 begin
  Timer1.Enabled:=false;
  Button1.Caption:='Пуск';
  ClientSocket.Active:= True;
  f:=not f;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 //z.Lock;

  //z.Brush.Color:=ClWhite;
  //z.FillRect(Canvas.ClipRect);

  //obj.Draw(z);
  if ClientSocket.Active  then
     ClientSocket.Socket.ReceiveBuf(dataBuf, 32);

  z.Brush.Color:=ClRed; 
  z.Ellipse(dataBuf[1] + 10, dataBuf[2] + 10,dataBuf[1] - 10, dataBuf[2] - 10);

//z.Unlock;
end;



procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
      ClientSocket.Active := false;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin

  myBuf[1]:=X;
  myBuf[2]:=Y;
  if ClientSocket.Active  then
     ClientSocket.Socket.SendBuf(myBuf, 32);

end;

end.
```

Server

```
unit ServerProject;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ScktComp;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
    procedure ServerSocket1ClientWrite(Sender: TObject;
      Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  sBufer : array [1..32] of Integer;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Port:=1234;
  ServerSocket1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Active := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  i:integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    with ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i] do
    begin
      ReceiveBuf(sBufer, 32);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientWrite(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  i:integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to ServerSocket1.Socket.ActiveConnections-1 do
  begin
    with ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[i] do
    begin
      SendBuf(sBufer, 32);
    end;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your painting code is in the wrong place and is painting to the wrong thing. In Windows programs you are meant to paint in response to a `WM_PAINT` message. You are not doing so. What's more, you have to paint on a device context that is provided by a call to `BeginPaint`.

The VCL wraps all those details up for you, but you still need to follow the rules. In your case I recommend that you add a `TPaintBox` component to your form. Then implement an `OnPaint` event handler for the paint box. Finally, whenever you wish to repaint the paint box, for example on a timer, call the `Invalidate` method of the paint box.

I suspect that you want your each new ellipse to be drawn in addition to the earlier drawn ellipses. In which case you are probably best served by drawing them to an off-screen bitmap first and then, when you come to paint to the paint box, draw that bitmap on the paint box. The point is that a window needs to be able to re-paint itself in its entirety. When you paint to a screen device, what you painted is lost the next time that window needs to be painted. So it's the responsibility of the application to be able to paint its entire self at any point, if it is asked.

More generally I urge you to stop using global variables. They will cause you no end of trouble. Prefer local variables wherever possible. If you need state to persist between different method calls, use member variables. The guiding principle is to use the narrowest scope possible.

Your current design uses a timer to poll for new data. That's a very poor approach. The most efficient and effective approach is to use synchronous blocking communication. Indy takes that approach. Windows sockets components instead tend to be used in an asynchronous mode. Irrespective of the relative merits of these two approaches, you should not be polling on a timer. If you do use asynchronous communication, then respond to new data by handling an event rather than polling.

Your program is currently trying to mix together GDI painting, and network communication. I suggest that you attempt to get on top of these concepts one at a time. Learn how to paint without the distraction of communication. Then when you have cracked painting, try to bring in the communication aspect.

Comment: but it drawing Ellipse correctly if I just would write something like this `z.Ellipse(X + 10, Y + 10, X- 10, Y - 10);` in `procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown`

Comment: OK, you don't believe me when I say that you need to paint in response to `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: No, I believe you (but actually I don't understood all things correctly at this moment, my english is not so good) but as I understand all I doing here it is just sending on server from some client array with data and then just send from server to all clients this array. And if thing like `z.Ellipse(X + 10, Y + 10, X- 10, Y - 10);` is working here(i checked it) why does not working  `z.Ellipse(dataBuf[1] + 10, dataBuf[2] + 10,dataBuf[1] - 10, dataBuf[2] - 10);`

Comment: I guess `dataBuf` doesn't contain what you think it contains. As I see it, your code is far too messy for you to make much real progress. You need to try to learn one thing at a time. As it stands you have too many different aspects of your code that are poorly designed and the problems with these different aspects will conflate your attempts to learn and understand. First of all I would get the painting code right.

Comment: Or perhaps you'd rather concentrate on the communications aspect first. No matter what, you need to decide which aspect you want help with and simply the problem down to focus on that aspect. At the moment I guess your communication doesn't work, and the painting is broken. Questions are meant to be narrow and deal with just a single issue. You have many issues. If you want to concentrate on one issue, say communication, you need to strip out the broken painting code and just have code that does communication.

Comment: Oh, well, sir, I trying. Actually I made a simple chat using `ServerSocket` and `ClientSocket` how it made in this tutorial http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm and it was working well. They used method `SendText();` there. Is there such big difference betweeen sending text and bufer?
> First of all I would get the painting code right. 
So, you mean I need to use TPaintBox?

Comment: Yes, I would probably use a `TPaintBox` for this. And as I said, if you want to build up a picture that contained all the ellipses passed over the network, then you need to keep track of them. One easy way to do that is in an off-screen bitmap.

Comment: Well, now it says `no adress specified`

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Are you expecting me to respond to that last comment? Remember that I cannot see your screen. I've no idea what you have done to the code since you posted the question. Or where the error appears. Please slow down and go right back to basics.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. I just added PaintBox and use it like this thats all `PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=ClRed;
PaintBox1.Canvas.Ellipse(dataBuf[1] + 10, dataBuf[2] + 10,dataBuf[1] - 10, dataBuf[2] - 10);`

Comment: Paint boxes work fine. You can't just post code with no context and expect us to understand. I've no idea where you put that code. I hope it's in the `OnPaint` event handler. If so then it's in the right place. Does the code even run? Are you calling `PaintBox1.Invalidate` anywhere? Is there anything sensible in `dataBuf`? Please please slow down. Go back to basics. Ask a new question that is entirely about painting. This one is a disaster.

Comment: Oh okay. Well I guess I should go back to basics. But however, dataBuf is empty and I don't know why

Comment: OK. So the comms are not working. Next step is to isolate that part of the program and work out why not. Concentrate on just one aspect at a time. You've built a big program and lots of it is failing. You don't know where to look. Build one bit at a time and only move on when each part works well on its own.

Comment: Oh, i got rid of almost all stuff, except part where client send data to server. And well I find that server is not correctly read data form client! I trying to fix it now